# Power Query / Power BI - How to move a cell value to a separate cell the easiest way?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

I want to move a single value from column B to column A, how can I achieve it in the most simplest way in Power Query / Query Editor (Power BI)?

Please see attached images.

[image]

[image]

I know I might need to declare a variable so please enlighten me. By the way, I will delete row 1 afterwards, promote my headers, and rename column2 as PERIOD.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is this data coming from in the first place?  I think it might be better to fix the format outside of Power BI

Comment: I understand that I can simply do that but I would like to fix it within Power BI. For added knowledge as well.

Comment: You're going to need to write a custom shaping script (advanced mode) rather than using column formulas. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/quick-tour-of-the-power-query-m-formula-language

Comment: Hi JeffUK, I understand that M language runs Power Query and this will be likely be solved by an M language coding.However, some guided how-to's would be helpful as I don't know what to do with that Let In statement. Anyway, I will still keep trying until someone posts a complete solution.

Comment: If I consider your first image as input, can you please add another sample with the output you wants from them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be along the lines of what you want to do.

If I start with this table named as Table1:

[image]

Then I click on the *fx* to the left of the formula bar:

[image]

And type `= Table.InsertRows(Source, Table.RowCount(Source), {[Column2 = Source[KP20 rate]{0}, KP20 rate = null, Column4 = null]})` into the formula bar:

[image]

I used Table.InsertRows to create a new row in Table1. Source is the name of the latest state of Table1 after it is pulled into Power Query and before I do this step. So I actually use Source as the name of the table for this step instead of Table1. (Each applied step basically results in its own table. You probably know this already, but others may not.) So for this step I use Source as the table name in the Table.InsertRows statement. Then, since I want the new row to appear at the bottom of Source, I just enter the Table.RowCount of Source as the row number location for the new row. Then I enter each of the Columns' names and their values to be added. For Column2, I entered the value "Source[KP20 rate]{0}." Source[KP20 rate]{0} basically treats column KP20 rate as a list, where {0} serves as a pointer to the first item in the list. To target the second item in Source[KP20 rate] you would use Source[KP20 rate]{1}. You can see that I set the values for the other two columns (KP20 rate and Column4) to null.

The result:

[image]

Here's the M code in case you want to see it:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Custom1 = Table.InsertRows(Source, Table.RowCount(Source), {[Column2 = Source[KP20 rate]{0}, KP20 rate = null, Column4 = null]})
in
    Custom1
```

Comment: Hi Marc Pincince, thank you very much. This is exactly what I need. Much obliged.